# Exclamation point inside a sentence

Tags: typography, punctuation

While reading [the free Kindle edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00846QWEU) of [*She*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/She%3a_A_History_of_Adventure) by H. Rider Haggard (originally published in 1887), I noticed sentences like this one:

> But now, to my intense horror, I *knew* that I could never put away the vision of those glorious eyes; and alas! the very *diablerie* of the woman, whilst it horrified and repelled, attracted in even a greater degree.

Notice the “alas!” in the middle of a sentence. I have never seen exclamation point in the middle of a sentence used like this before. Was this a common practice at the time this book was published? What is the history of this practice?

Comment: This is an antiquated style of punctuation, seen primarily in pulp fiction of the late 19th and early 20th centuries. It is a kind of parenthetical intensifier. Or you could call it an inline aside. Nowadays, such a thing would probably be rendered in parentheses complete  — "... and (alas!) the very *diablerie* of the woman" — or with just the exclamation mark in parentheses: "... and alas (!) the very ...." etc.

Comment: @Robusto Why don't you post that as an answer?

Comment: If you insist. See below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering per OP's request:

This is an antiquated style of punctuation, seen primarily in pulp fiction of the late 19th and early 20th centuries. It is a kind of parenthetical intensifier. Or you could call it an inline aside. Nowadays, such a thing would probably be rendered in parentheses complete — "... and (alas!) the very *diablerie* of the woman" — or with just the exclamation mark in parentheses: "... and alas (!) the very ...." etc.

Answer (score 3):

It's just to clarify that the term (alas, in this case) should be stressed.

Other ways to achieve the same result are:

- (alas!)
- alas (!)

Here's another example:

> The *huge* crowd (1337 persons!) gathering in my front yard wasn't really that friendly looking.

Here, the "(1337 persons!)" stress the fact that it was indeed a *huge* crowd to be gathering in the front yard.

For the history of this usage, see the first comment on the original question.